# Использование платежных систем в Android приложении

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Необходимо создать простенькое приложение, в котором пользователь может выбрать сумму и перевести ее со своего.
Как это лучше реализовать? Какие есть платежные системы с android api?

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK PayPal

Comment: одно маленькое замечание к комментарию @Deadkenny    
есть шанс поймать бан в гугл плее за обход их платежной системы.    
Советую разобраться в их правилах сначала...

Comment: @metalurgus Если они будут использовать гугл плей :)